# Type base64Binary is not declared or is not a simple type

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am getting this error and don't know how to fix it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
           xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
      <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
                 schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>XML Digital Signature schema imported to support 
                            signatures of messages and contents.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:import>
      ....
      <xs:simpleType name="APP_base64" >
         <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>Representación base64 de la imagen </xs:documentation>
         </xs:annotation>
         <xs:restriction base="base64Binary"/>
      </xs:simpleType>
```

This line gives a warning `<xs:restriction base="base64Binary"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<xs:restriction base="base64Binary"/>
```

to

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:base64Binary"/>
```

Comment: Hi! Would you mind to revise another XSD question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39834772/xsd-signature-issue

Comment: @Dimi: Sure, I added an [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39835453/290085) there for you.