# XSD Signature issue

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xsd, digital-signature, xml-signature

I cannot resolve this error about `<xs:element ref="ds:Signature"/>`.
I need some help please.

> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. Schema
>   validation warning: The 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#:Signature'
>   el ement is not declared. Line 162, position 8.
>
> Warning: Schema could not be validated. Class generation may fail or
>   may produce  incorrect results.
>
> Warning: cannot generate classes because no top-level elements with
>   complex type  were found.

**XSD**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
            xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
  attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
             schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>

             <xs:complexType name="SobreCheques">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Definition of the ...</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
             ...
      <xs:element ref="ds:Signature"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Schema http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd accessible from the machine?

Comment: ok. what if you save the schema locally and refer it in `schemalocation` , does it still cant resolve the namespace.

Comment: @ulab Would you mind to suggest correct syntax to use it locally please.

Comment: `<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
  schemaLocation="file:///D:/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd" />`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Retrieving `xmldsig-core-schema.xsd` from the W3C site can take a long time, causing timeouts.

Instead, use a cached local copy in the same directory as your XSD,

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
           schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>
```

or use an absolute path as shown by [@ulab in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39834772/xsd-signature-issue/39835453#comment66960280_39834772):

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"   
           schemaLocation="file:///D:/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd" />
```

See also [How to reference a local XML Schema file correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19253402/290085)

Comment: AdditionaI, make sure the XSD file from W3C is accessible from a browser. I had the same problem and even if I added the file locally it didn't work. The problem for me it was that my computer it was behind a proxy server and the W3C site was blocked. After I fixed the access to the XSD file I was able to generate the classes. Not sure if this issue it was specific only to my setup or not.